# connect redux function is not working with react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to configure redux with react-native I face an error called undefined is not a function when try to call an action from my component , 
It seems that action() function is not called correctly , I can't access state as prop inside the form component. 
This is my code :

**index.android.js**

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
  import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
  // import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
  import reducers from './src/reducers';
  import { Form } from './src/components/Form';
  import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

  export class App extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
      //here we will handle firebase sutup process for the authntication purpose . 
    }

    render() {
      const store = createStore(reducers);
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Form />
        </Provider>
      );
    }
  }

  const styles = {
    main: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    }
  };

  AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', () => App);
```

**Form.js**

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import { connect } from "react-redux";
 import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
 import { Image } from "react-native";
 import { emailChanged } from "../actions";
 import {
Container,
ContainerSection,
Button,
Input
} from ".././components/common";

export class Form extends Component {
onEmailChange(text) {
    //call the action creator for the email
    this.props.emailChanged(text);
}

onPasswordChange(text) {
    //call the action creator for the password
}

onButtonPress() {
    //do something
}

renderButton() {
    return <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>Log in</Button>;
}

render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <ContainerSection>
                <Image source={require("../../images/logo.png")} />
            </ContainerSection>
            <ContainerSection>
                {/* email input  */}
                <Input
                    label="Email"
                    placeholder="email@gmail.com"
                    value={this.props.email}
                    onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
                    keyboardType="email-address"
                />
            </ContainerSection>
            <ContainerSection>
                {/* password input  */}
                <Input
                    label="password"
                    placeholder="password"
                    value={this.props.password}
                    onChangeText={this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)}
                    secure
                />
            </ContainerSection>
            <ContainerSection>{this.renderButton()}</ContainerSection>
        </Container>
    );
}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    email: state.auth.email,
    password: state.auth.password
};
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
return bindActionCreators({ emailChanged }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(
mapStateToProps,
mapDispatchToProps
)(Form);
```

**index.js (inside actions folder )**

```
    import { EMAIL_CHANGED, PASSWORD_CHANGED } from './types';
    //it is an action creator 
    export const emailChanged = (text) => {
        return {
            type: EMAIL_CHANGED, 
            payload: text
        };
    };

    //it is an action creator 
    export const passwordChanged = (text) => {
        return {
            type: PASSWORD_CHANGED, 
            payload: text 
        };
    };
```

**index.js(inside reducers folder)**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import AuthReducer from './AuthReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    auth: AuthReducer
    //   employeeForm: EmployeeFormReducer,
    //   employees: EmployeeReducer
});
```

**AuthReducer.js**

```
  import {
      EMAIL_CHANGED,
      PASSWORD_CHANGED
    } from '../actions/types';

  const INITIAL_STATE = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };

  export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case EMAIL_CHANGED:
          return { ...state, email: action.payload };
        case PASSWORD_CHANGED:
          return { ...state, password: action.payload };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
```

[image: This is the error returned]

Comment: I tried this also but it didn't work , I guess the connect function is not being called, nothings mapped to props neither actions nor state.

Comment: I read the documentation and tried all the possible choices , also I searched google, but nothings worked for sorry .

Comment: did you try to `console.log(this.props)`

Comment: yes it returns an empty object {}.

Comment: Don't you need to bind the `method` to `this` btw?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153109/discussion-between-koox00-and-mahmoud-abd-al-kareem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the error, first of all I changed the structure of the code I put the Provider and the store at index.android.js directly, then after that I changed this function :

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ emailChanged }, dispatch);
}
```

to this :

```
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
   return {
    emailChanged: () => dispatch(emailChanged())
   }
}
```

without using bindActionCreators
then I installed the dependencies using yarn add , 

thanks to Sacha Best notes also you may need to make sure you have the following packages installed via npm :

```
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react-native": "^3.0.2",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
```

also make sure your .babelrc has:

```
{
"presets": ["react-native", "es2015", "stage-0"],
"sourceMaps": true,
"plugins": [
["transform-decorators-legacy"],
]
}
```

**important note to consider that : Both the React and Redux teams generally discourage the use of connect() as a decorator, for a variety of reasons. The spec is still unstable, the Babel plugins are still changing, and even when the plugins are working, using connect() as a decorator can lead to unexpected behavior from a developer's point of view.**

This worked for me, but if it still doesn't work with you try to use connect() as function not as decorator .

these changes solved the error ! hope that this will help you . 
Thank you all.

Answer (score 10):

I also face this problem and spend lot of time.. This issue is not working react-redux connect in this component. Because excute

```
export class Form extends Component
```

Therefore not execute the

```
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    emailChanged,
)(Form);
```

**Solution :**

remove the **export** keyword
eg :

```
 class Form extends Component
```

and import where this component you **must use**

```
 import Form  from './src/components/Form';
```

**Don't use**

```
 import { Form } from './src/components/Form';
```

in this case make changes as follows,

**index.android.js**

```
  import Form  from './src/components/Form';
```

**Form.js**

```
export class Form extends Component {
...
}
 export default connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        emailChanged ,
    )(Form);
```

Hope this is helpful for you...
Happy Coding...!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In my case the problem was that I imported my component with { }. when I removed the curly braces it started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try just passing emailChanged directly.

return bindActionCreators(emailChanged, dispatch);

Comment: It didn't work , the connect function is not being called .

Comment: @MahmoudAbdALKareem If you haven't already done so, I would add in redux dev tools so you can analyze your store and see what's happening there.  If you're not even getting a store object, then your problem may exist in your index.android.js with the way you're configuring your store.

Comment: I will try to use redux dev tools hope this will give me hints  , I'm stuck for three days , I tried many many solutions nothings worked , the problem is with the connect function it is not being called , I tried to call it in different ways ,  do you think the problem is with the new version ?

Comment: what are your react , react-native , redux , react-redux versions ?

Comment: @MahmoudAbdALKareem I'm using the latest versions of everything and haven't had any problems.  First thing to check is when your <Form /> mounts, do you have a store object that you can see in redux dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

try to use dispatch calling from any component. like this

**Form.js**

```
this.props.dispatch(emailChanged(text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try something this in in your **Form.js**

```
    import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
    import { Image } from 'react-native';
    import { emailChanged } from '../actions';
    import { Container, ContainerSection, Button, Input } from '.././components/common';

    export class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.onPasswordChange= this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)
    }
        onEmailChange(text) {
            //call the action creator for the email 
            this.props.emailChanged(text);
        }

        onPasswordChange(text) {
            //call the action creator for the password
        }

        onButtonPress() {
            //do something
        }

        renderButton() {

            return (
                <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
                    Log in
                </Button>
            );
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <Container>
                    <ContainerSection>
                        <Image source={require('../../images/logo.png')} />
                    </ContainerSection>
                    <ContainerSection>
                        {/* email input  */}
                        <Input
                            label="Email"
                            placeholder="email@gmail.com"
                            value={this.props.email}
                            onChangeText={this.onEmailChange.bind(this)}
                            keyboardType="email-address"
                        />
                    </ContainerSection>
                    <ContainerSection>
                        {/* password input  */}
                        <Input
                            label="password"
                            placeholder="password"
                            value={this.props.password}
                            onChangeText={this.onPasswordChange}
                            secure
                        />
                    </ContainerSection>
                    <ContainerSection>
                        {this.renderButton()}
                    </ContainerSection>
                </Container>
            );
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
            email: state.auth.email,
            password: state.auth.password
        };
    };

    FlipCardWithImage.propTypes = {
    emailChanged : PropTypes.func,

}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ emailChanged }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Form);
```

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me yesterday. But when I copied all the code files to the previous project, it worked. So it must be something with the corrupted installation, as the installation has been done the same way using same packages. In one project connect works, in the other, it does not.

Comment: did you check my answer ? may be some babel plugins are missed, or as I mentioned that both the React and Redux teams generally discourage the use of connect() as a decorator, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Well, the new corrupted and the old working one, have the same node modules and same packages. The code is now exactly the same, but one works and the other does not. Could you please paste the code of your provider in the index.js? Maybe that would help me out. PS: I am working coincidently on the same tutorial and same project as you were and having the exactly same issue.

Comment: you can check the full source code here, https://github.com/MahmoudAbdAlKareem/rainbow-react-native-app .